# Using conemu terminal with Xming

Tags: ssh, x11, conemu, xming

I am using [ConEmu](http://sourceforge.net/projects/conemu/) which is a great terminal for Windows. 
I am also using MobaXterm which has a built in X server to allow me to run Linux applications have have their GUIs run on my Windows machine.

What I would love is to be able to achieve the same thing with ConEmu. Is it possible to forward X via SSH on ConEmu and have this work with Xming?
I tried loading Xming and logging into my linux machine via SSH from a standard windows cmd.exe terminal in ConEmu but it doesn't work. 
Perhaps this question is not relevent to ConEmu but perhaps ConEmu has some magic I'm not aware of...

```
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug2: callback start
debug1: X11 forwarding requested but DISPLAY not set
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
debug2: channel 0: request pty-req confirm 1
debug2: channel 0: request shell confirm 1
debug2: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: PTY allocation request accepted on channel 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd adjust 2097152
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: shell request accepted on channel 0
```

Comment: Why not to ask xming authors?

Answer (score 4):

[EDITED] : That doesn't work because in the same time, MobaXTermn was running and i was using their X11 forwarding.

sorry

---

> I managed to forward X11 with Cmder (which is based on ConEmu) so I
>   hope this will work !
>
> Once you have lauched your Xming server on your local computer, look
>   for "where" it display it : simply hover your mouse over the Xming
>   notification in your notification tray icon, you will see a number,
>   meaning it's diplayed on locahost:number
>
> [image: >> screen capt <<].
>
> In example, when using MobaXTerm it is displayed on `localhost:11.0`.
>
> Once you know that, connect to your remote server as you normally do
>   and on the prompt type
>
> ```
> DISPLAY=XMING_ID;export DISPLAY;
> ```
>
> where XMING_ID is where you displayed it ( eg : `localhost:0.0` or
>   `locahost:11.0` )
>
> Then, graphic windows will be forwarded until you close this session.
>   Then repeat. Just remember to launch Xming before your ssh session.
>
> Hope this will help !

Comment: no worries, thanks for the attempt! I encountered the same thing. It worked when using mobaxterm at the same time.

Comment: Although I'm resurrecting a 6 year old post, this totally works :P

Comment: @GerhardBurger - you mean with MobaXterm running in the background?

Comment: @GregoryKuhn Uhhh, no, that I didn't get from the question, I must admit ;)